# Google Drive and French Special Characters

Tags: google-drive-api

Inserting a file mimetype of 'text/doc' or 'text/plain' via the API having french special characters.

The file gets added without problem except when you go on the google drive file view or 'preview' the special character agrave 'à' is not recognised but all other special characters are.

Can i add something else that might affect ?

```
$created_file = $service->files->insert(
    $file, array(
       'convert' => true,
       'data' => $data,
       'mimeType' => $mime_type
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you're getting your data, you may want to try encoding as UTF-8 before you submit, using PHP's utf8_encode:

```
'data' => utf8_encode($data),
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: I know this and its not fixing my issue in anyway because all the special characters are displayed except agrave 'à'.